# Transformation $Y = \sqrt{K \frac{X}{1-X}}$ Where $X \sim Beta(a,b)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

> Consider a Beta distributed random variable, $X \sim Beta(a,b)$ Then consider the transform $$Y = \sqrt{K\frac{X}{1-X}}$$ where $K > 0$ is a constant.

How could you go about finding the PDF of $Y$? Is it a named distribution?

It seems that you cannot apply the transformation formula, since the mapping is not strictly monotonic and doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: Isn't the denominator $1-X$? in this form, $X-1<0$, and with $K>0$ you will get a negative term inside the square root.  Even with this change, doesn't appear to be any common named distribution.  $X\sim Beta(a,b)$, $X/(1-X)\sim $ Beta prime with parameters $a,b$.

Comment: Yes you are exactly right, the denominator should be $1-X$. Do you have a link to the proof that $X \sim Beta(a,b) \iff X/(1-X) \sim BP(a,b)$? Also, does it seem correct that $Y$ is distributed as a generalised beta of the second kind? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_beta_distribution#Generalized_beta_of_the_second_kind_(GB2)

Comment: Have a look at this https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/05%3A_Special_Distributions/5.18%3A_The_Beta_Prime_Distribution

Comment: Hint: use $P(Y\le y)=P\left(X\le\tfrac{y^2}{K+y^2}\right)$ to compute $Y$'s PDF.